# Application freezes while using IO C#

Tags: c#, io

I don't know what causes the issue, but whenever I try to read from a text file in this situation, the application freezes.

```
private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int totalVotes = 0;
   int votesFirst = 0;
   int votesSecond = 0;

   string firstClub;
   string secondClub;

   FileStream fs = null;
   StreamReader sr = null;

   if (tb1.Text == "" || tb2.Text == "")
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Fill in the fields");
   }
   else
   {
       firstClub = tb1.Text;
       secondClub = tb2.Text;

       try
       {
           fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\dluuk\\source\\repos\\PopularFootballClubs\\Polls\\bin\\Debug\\FootballClubs.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
           sr = new StreamReader(fs);
           string s = sr.ReadLine();

           while (s != null)
           {
               if (s.Contains(firstClub))
               {
                   votesFirst++;
                   totalVotes++;
               }
               else if (s.Contains(secondClub))
               {
                   votesSecond++;
                   totalVotes++;
               }
           }
       }
       catch (IOException ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("something wrong happened");
       }
       finally
       {
           lblTotal.Text = totalVotes.ToString();
           lbl1.Text = votesFirst.ToString();
           lbl2.Text = votesSecond.ToString();

           if (sr != null) { sr.Close(); }

           if (fs != null) { fs.Close(); }
       }
   }
}
```

I'm closing connection and the path is correct, because I don't get any exceptions at this current state so I really can't see the problem. Maybe you can help?

Comment: You aren't updating `s` at all, so your loop is infinite.

Comment: It is not frozen, the app has entered an infinite loop. There is no exit from the while loop

Comment: You need `string s; while ((s = sr.ReadLine())!= null) { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't updating `s` at all, so your loop is infinite. It's reading the first line, then looping over and over again, using the same line each time because `ReadLine()` is not called again in the scope of the loop (and thus you never reach the end of the file - or even line 2).

You could change to something like this:

```
string s;

while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (s.Contains(firstClub))
    {
        votesFirst++;
        totalVotes++;
    }
    else if (s.Contains(secondClub))
    {
        votesSecond++;
        totalVotes++;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should put `using` statements around your `Stream`s. They are disposable and you won't need to handle it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`while (s != null)`

You never change `s` in the loop, so it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Update `s` at the end of the loop:

```
while (s != null)
{
  // do stuff
  s = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help